# Как получить случайное число в интервале?

Tags: python

Задание псевдослучайной величины из интервала [0,1], как написать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import random

print random.random()
```

Comment: "Ехал рандом через рандом, видит рандом - рандом, рандом..."
Извините, не удержался ))